# Calling a function on swf in facebook from javascript

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, externalinterface

I have a game on facebook which is talking to its javascript container. I am using ExternalInterface to pass parameters to the JS - this is working flawlessly. The problem starts when I want to pass data to the SWF - when running the game outside of facebook, everything works smoothly - I can pass data to the SWF with no problems. However, when running under facebook - then I get the "error on NPObject" message.
I have allowscriptaccess set to true, and I can still call JS function on the page, just not the other way around, and only when running under facebook...

**Edit:**
Apparently, this issue happens when a user disables the secure browsing in their facebook privacy settings, so this must be some cross-domain issue.

Comment: http://www.wrichards.com/blog/2009/02/error-calling-method-on-npobject/

Comment: I have tried that solution, and even added this:
System.security.allowDomain("*");

Still, doesn't work...